# media transcoding, codec in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, codec

I would be developing a media player app in hopefully wpf but i am having trouble with a few aspects.

I know that i can do some basic stuff with audio n video using MediaElement class in c# but i was wondering that 
1. i also need to stream online videos and save them in different qualities(resolution) and formats and also might extrfact audio from them
2. I would be needing to convert and play existing files on my system.
3. Video/screen capture
4. Substitles etc. 
5. Equalizer

I heard about ffmpeg

But i am confused that if i could use it with c#.
So help me if there is something better to help with max. Of the issues i have here. And what are the things i need to read about. Is there any tutorial that would help me out.

Comment: You're asking very complex broad questions and asking for references to other sites, neither of which are good matches for questions here. A better question might be to post some code you've tried that isn't working for a very specific aspect of one of the things you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the response,I have'nt written any code yet.. i was wondering if anyone could guide me what api to use for the queries i mentioned above? i need tutorials for them. Where can i get them?

Comment: Questions asking for tutorials aren't a good fit for StackOverflow. You've picked a **very complex** project to work on -- all very challenging topics in their own regard.

Comment: Yes i know about that but where should i start?